# Shopify / Liquid - Count articles in blog without pagination

Tags: shopify, liquid

I have a blog with 28 articles in it on Shopify. I am paginating by 5 articles for the blog, i.e. `{% paginate blog.articles by 5 %}`

I am trying to count the number of articles in the blog and have tried both the following methods:

**Method 1:**

```
{% for article in blog.articles %}
  {% assign count = count | plus: 1 %}
{% endfor %}

{{ count }}
```

**Method 2:**

```
{{ blog.articles.size }}
```

The issue I am facing is that in both cases, the output is 5. The answer I am expecting is 28 - clearly it is only counting the number of article within the page. I also am trying to filter by tags, where I want to see the amount of results from the tag search. Any solutions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: use `blog.articles_count` to get total count

Comment: @Onkar - That would be good to post as an answer, possibly with a supporting link to the relevant page in Shopify's Liquid Reference :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, You need to check the default Shopify liquid object `blog` and its property named `articles_count`, to check about `blog.articles_count` use this [documentation](https://shopify.dev/docs/themes/liquid/reference/objects/blog#blog-articles_count) link.